# How to ignore semi colon in a string in mysql using python

Tags: python, mysql, escaping

I am trying to insert a string into MySql using python.
Sometimes the string has a couple of semicolons in them.

Due to this only a part of the string gets inserted.
I tried escaping the string but it doesnt seem to help.

Example code goes below

```
string = "Hello; World"
string = string.replace("'","''")  //this is done incase i have "'" in a different scenario
string = re.escape(string)

update table set column = '"+string+"';
```

When i insert the above code, it inserts just "Hello" instead of "Hello; World"

Help would be of immense help.

Comment: Using `string` as a variable name is bad form

Comment: Use parameters when constructing queries in Python, rather than munging the query string.

Comment: I need the semi colon to be inserted into the table column. So i cant strip the semi colons

Comment: unfortunately, this is a huge query .. and i am not in a position to change the full part of the query. Is there another way, Gordon ?

Comment: Not sure if that would work, but did you try to escape the semicolon? Like `string.replace(';', '\;')`?

Comment: i assumed that re.escape does the escaping part. Instead of manually escaping every special character in the future.

Comment: Can you share the code which is actually inserting into database?

Comment: Your code snippet is not valid. Please post the minimal verifiable code needed to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't have this problem using the db api the right way (using placeholders and explicit parameters):

```
>>> sql = "update auth_user set last_name = %s where id=%";
>>> args = ("FOO;BAR", 1)
>>> c.execute(sql, args)
>>> c.execute("select last_name from auth_user where id=1")
1L
>>> c.fetchone()
(u'FOO;BAR',)
```

Not only will this take care of properly escaping your arguments, but it will also protect you from [sql injections](http://bobby-tables.com/).